# Mandela coins and iTunes gift cards — is this a scam?

Tags: scams, gift-card

I joined this group on Facebook about Mandela coins and asked how much they would offer me for my 38 coins. One person offered me 2 million South African rands and another person offered me 5 million rands, but both are saying I must get a R450 iTunes gift card and send it to them for confirmation from the DHL company. I even tried asking if there is any other method and they said no.

Is this true or a scam? Can I trust it?

Comment: It's one of the most well-known scams in existence.  100% scam.  Extremely well-known scam.

Comment: Without any explanation , i do believe you , it really is a scam and i'm not going to still entertain her , thank you guys!

Comment: @Vicky's answer is correct, plus your R5 coins are worth R5 apiece, making the lot worth R190. I hope you didn't pay more than that to *obtain* those coins.

Comment: If it sounds too good to be true, it probably is.

Comment: no i did not pay anything for it i just collected them by going to the shops and asking for those coins and giving them the normal R5's in exchange

Comment: They are trying to buy your coins, but they are asking you to spend money? This is confusing. Are they saying that they'll use the money to pay for the shipping? Why don't you just pay for the shipping yourself?

Comment: You can trust it, in which case you will become R450 poorer.

Answer (score 11):

The words "iTunes gift card" and "DHL" are enough red flags. Yes, this is a scam. Cut off contact, block them and move along.

Also, a quick google shows that Mandela coins are not particularly valuable: https://www.businessinsider.co.za/how-much-is-mandela-r5-coin-worth-price-2020-2

Answer (score 5):

When someone promises you money, but expects you to first pay some money before they pay you, then you are very likely dealing with someone trying to pull an [advance fee fraud](https://www.investor.gov/protect-your-investments/fraud/types-fraud/advance-fee-fraud) on you.